# Wordpress choose wrong database

Tags: database, wpdb

I have 2 databases. When I include the database connection (`with a include('filename.php');`) wordpress acts really strange.

I can't login, the wordpress username and password is right but it tries to connect to the other database (which I can see when I turn debug on).

```
WordPress database error: [Table 'api.apiwp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM apiwp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_pages' LIMIT 1
WordPress database error: [Table 'api.apiwp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM apiwp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_calendar' LIMIT 1
WordPress database error: [Table 'api.apiwp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM apiwp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_links' LIMIT 1
WordPress database error: [Table 'api.apiwp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM apiwp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_tag_cloud' LIMIT 1
WordPress database error: [Table 'api.apiwp_options' doesn't exist]
SELECT option_value FROM apiwp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_nav_menu' LIMIT 1
```

It's like they can not separate the connections. Anything that can help me in the right direction?

The content also stops working.

**Edit: Clearifying**

My Database connection:

```
function ir_mysql() {
    global $dbm;

    if(empty($dbm)){
        $dbm = new Mysql(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
    }
    return $dbm;
}
```

mysql.class.php

```
class Mysql {

    // Variabler 
    // -----------------------------
    private $db;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $host;
    private $linkid;
    private $result;

function __construct($host, $user, $password, $db) {
        try {
            $this->db = $db;
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->host = $host;

            $this->connect();
            $this->select();
            mysql_set_charset('utf8', $this->linkid);
        } catch (exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }


    function Connect() {
        try {
            $this->linkid = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
            if (!$this->linkid) {
                throw new Exception(mysql_error());
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }


    function Select() {
        try {
            if (!mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->linkid)) {
                throw new Exception("Cannot access the selected database");
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }


    function Query($sql) {
        try {
            $this->result = @mysql_query($sql, $this->linkid);

            if (!$this->result) {

                throw new Exception("Mysql query error: \n <br />" . mysql_error() . "<br />" . mysql_errno());
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if (ir_admin()) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $this->result;
    }

function Close() {
        mysql_close($this->linkid);
}

}
```

So if I'm querying something new I do like this: `ir_mysql()->query("SELECT....");`

My method and wordpress method are not playing well.

Comment: I don't follow what "include the database connection" means. What exactly is happening in that file?

Comment: Please use the `$wpdb` class. You can read more about it in [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

Comment: Why don't you just use the `wpdb` class? You're aware the PHP mysql extension is deprecated and removed in newer versions of PHP? You should be using mysqli or PDO instead

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested. I made it work.

I made a plugin and in the main php-file I wrote this.

```
<?php

function ir_load(){
    include_once(ABSPATH . 'load.php');
}

function db_fix_login(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->select(DB_NAME);
}

add_action("wp_head","db_fix_login", 0);

ir_load();
db_fix_login();

?>
```

The `ir_load()` contains the database connection to my database. I made it a function in case I needed to change or include it somewhere else.

db_fix_login needed to go to `wp_head()` (since I use `get_header()` on my subpage to keep wordpress functionality).

Everything worked except that I got logged out all the time if I only runned `ir_load()`.

So after trying everything: Why not run `db_fix_login()` right after? It worked. No errors or anything!

Comment: Just curious what a `non-db database` is...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Gone now.